# Iterate checkboxes in a named form with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can easily iterate over all the checkboxes in a given page with jQuery, but I don't quite understand how I can iterate over the checkboxes in a specific form with a specific name, as my module may be used on a page with any number of other types of forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('form[name="formName"] :checkbox').each(function() { });`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="s" id="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="s" id="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="p" id="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="p" id="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="s" id="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="s" id="6" />
```

and the Script

```
   $('#formId input[name=s]').each(function(index){
       alert($(this).attr("id")) 
    });
```

Here is the sample http: http://jsfiddle.net/Crwy4/2/

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
$("form[name='frm1']").find(":checkbox");
```

not you can iterate via `each`.

also please refer to :

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form[name="formName"] input:checkbox').each(function() {
    //Do something
});
```

For better performance use **input:checkbox**.  From the jquery API:

"$(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('*:checkbox'), so $('input:checkbox') should be used instead."

Answer (score 0):

It would probably look something like:

```
$('form[name='example'] input[type='checkbox']').each(function(){
       //your stuff goes here
 });
```

I'm not sure of the performance implications of this, though. These are relying on [jQuery attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).